# {no answer yet} Getting comment scores from the YouTube JSON Api

Tags: javascript, json, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I really want to be able to retrieve comment scores from youtube's JSON API, like this example:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/QH2-TGUlwu4/comments?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true

I was not able to find any hints of a comment score in the above link. Does anyone know of a way to retrieve scores from these comments?

Answer (score 0):

Does this URL format help ?

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=QH2-TGUlwu4/comments&v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true

It contains

```
gd$rating: {
   average: 4.737795,
   max: 5,
   min: 1,
   numRaters: 846063,
   rel: "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall"
 }
```

(This should be a comment, but a little too large for one)

Comment: Sorry, that's for videos (check the url you posted). Thanks anyway!